# Определение утечки памяти в консольном приложении C++ с помощью MinGW

Tags: память, mingw

В режиме отладки простой консольной программы:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <iostream> 

int main()
{
  int tmpDbgFlag = _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG);
  tmpDbgFlag |= _CRTDBG_DELAY_FREE_MEM_DF;
  tmpDbgFlag |= _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF;
  tmpDbgFlag |= _CRTDBG_DELAY_FREE_MEM_DF;
  _CrtSetDbgFlag(tmpDbgFlag);
  int* p = NULL, N = 3;
  p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
  // free(p);
  return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio сообщает об утечки памяти:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects -> normal block at 0x000001A602D37C50, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <            > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD
```

CodeBlocks c MinGW и gdb сообщает только, что variable 'p' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]|"
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить компилятор (отладчик), чтобы появились сообщения об утечки памяти.

Comment: Есть такой heob, но не могу сказать насколько удобно его будет использовать с C::B, в qtcreator он интегрирован

Comment: спасибо большое, очень полезная информация.